# Approximation of a smooth function by smooth functions with compact support

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ be a bounded open set, and let $h \in C^\infty(U)$.

Since $h \in L^p(U)$ for every $1 \leq p \leq \infty$, there exists a sequence $(h_j) \subset C_c^\infty(U)$ such that
$$h_j \rightarrow h \quad \text{strongly in} \quad L^p(U)$$
provided $p < \infty$.

> Does $\nabla h_j \rightarrow \nabla h$ in $L^p(U)$ ?

I know that if $(f_n) \subset L^1_{\mathrm{loc}}(U)$ is such that in $L^1_{\mathrm{loc}}(U)$,
$$f_n \rightarrow f, \quad \partial_j f_n \rightarrow g_j \quad \forall j \in [1,N],$$
then $G = \nabla f$, where $G$ has components $g_j$, $1 \leq j \leq N$.

> Does there exists $H$ such that $\nabla h_j \rightarrow H$ in $L^p(U;\mathbb{R}^N)$
>   ?

Comment: Maybe this can be useful: http://www.pitt.edu/~hajlasz/OriginalPublications/Hajlasz-NoteOnMeyers-ExpoMath-11-1993-377-379.pdf

Comment: Do you want to know whether the statement holds for any approximating sequence or whether there exists some approximating sequence such that the claim is satisfied?

Comment: @saz I want to know whether there exists a sequence $(h_j) \subset C_c^\infty(U)$ such that $h_j \rightarrow h$ in $L^p(U)$ and $\nabla h_j \rightarrow \nabla h$ in $L^p(U;\mathbb{R}^N)$, for any $1 \leq p < \infty$.

Comment: "since $ h \in L^{p}$" I dont see how this is a valid conclusion under the assumptions you made. Let $U = (0,1)$ and $h(x) = 1/x$. Then we have $h \in C^{\infty}(U)$, but $h \notin L^{1}(U)$

Comment: I forgot specifying that $h \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R^N})$ and $U = \mathrm{supp} \, h \cap \Omega \neq \emptyset$ for some open set $\Omega$. Hence $h \in L^p(U)$.